# Adding lists of numbers in Pari/GP

Tags: pari

I've got a .txt file, which contains a sequence of numbers as follows:

```
a_1
+a_2 
+a_3 
+a_4
+a_5
...
```

Fix some positive integer `n`. Using Pari/GP, how can I write down the sequence `[a_1, a_1 + a_2*n, a_1 + a_2*n + a_3*n, ...]` as a Pari/GP vector? I've been told that I shold use `concat(-,-)`, but I don't know how to do utilize the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I create a file `C:\temp\example.txt` with the contents:

```
100
+300
+301
+10101
```

then I can use the following:

```
gp > a=readvec("C:\\temp\\example.txt")
%1 = [100, 300, 301, 10101]
gp > b=vector(#a,i,a[1]+n*sum(j=2,i,a[j]))
%2 = [100, 300*n + 100, 601*n + 100, 10702*n + 100]
```

Here `a` is simply a vector representation of the file lines, and `b` is a vector with `#a` components whose `i`th entry is `a[1]` plus `n` times the sum from `j=2` to `i` of `a[j]`.

You could also assign a value to `n`, like `n=666`, before you declare `b`.

Hope this was what you meant.